# Conjecture about unbiased 2d random walks with decreasing step size

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

This is a more generalized strengthening of [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833205/how-often-do-we-expect-a-random-walk-with-decreasing-step-size-to-cross-0?noredirect=1#comment10290155_4833205). A rigorous proof has been provided by Eric to that question. However, I believe there to be a more general claim.

Consider unbiased 2-d random walks $S_n$ where the $n$-th step has  (non-random)  length $c_i > 0$, with $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i = \infty$   and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i^2 < \infty$ . When we say that a random walk crosses a number $a$, we mean that $a$ is sandwiched by $S_{n-1} $ and $S_n$ for some $n$ .

Then I conjecture that for any such random walk $S_n$ and any number $a$, the expected number of times that $a$ is crossed by $S_n$ is $\infty$

Comment: Just to be clear, can you confirm the only changes from the linked earlier question (which I would call a 1D random walk) are (1) you are not restricting to the case $c_i=\frac1i$ and (2) you are not restricting to the case $a=0\,$? You still have each step $\pm c_i$ with equal probability

Answer (score 0):

My justification:

The variance  $S_n - S_m $ is bounded for every $n,m$. Thus the difference between the maximum and minimum of $S$ has finite expectation. Also the random walk will converge almost surely. But the total amount of distance traversed is infinite.  Let $ Y_n$ be the amount of times that $S_n$  is crossed between $S_{m-1} $ and $S_m$. Intuitively, the expectation $E(Y_n)$ goes to $\infty$ when $n$ goes to $\infty$. The expected number of future  returns / crosses  becomes infinite in the tail of the walk.  But on the other hand, for any $a$, $N>0$  and $\delta > 0$ , we can find some $a^*$ and $m>N$ , with  $|a-a^*| < \delta $ and $P(S_m = a^*) > 0 $